# Replace modal content by another modal content using $uibModal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a signin modal which has a link to signup modal. When user clicks on signup link, I want to replace the signin modal with signup modal without closing the signin modal. I have used $uibModal service for creating both signin and signup modals. Code for modals is as follows

```
$uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: 'signupModal.html',
                controller: 'SignUpModalCtrl',
                windowClass: '',
                backdrop: 'static'
            });

$uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: 'signinModal.tpl.html',
                controller: 'SignInModalCtrl',
                windowClass: '',
                backdrop: 'static'
            });
```

I'm trying to implement stateful modals using uibModal service. I know it can be done using angular ui-router but can it be done using uibModal? This is similar to shopping cart process where next modal content appears after user clicks on submit button from current modal.